# Python Dice Rolling game - How to check separate rolls and add total

Tags: python

Hi guys I am in the midst of creating a dice in game in python. Below is my working code. So far if a player were to roll the dice one time, I can easily check if the rolled number is 1, however how can I make it so that if I want to roll lets say 10 times, I want to be able to check if any of those 10 rolls, any of them equaled 1, and then stop it, if none equaled 1, I would add them all up. 
Basically How do I check the result of each seperate roll, and adding them up if a 1 is not rolled.

```
import random
import sys

def rollingdice(roll): #define function
    total = 0 #starting count
    for i in range(roll):
      total+= random.randint(1, 6)
    if total == 1:
      print("You rolled a 1: You have zero points for the round")
    else:
        print(total)
    main()

def main():
    roll=int(input("Player 1: How many times will you roll "))
    rollingdice(roll)
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a variable to hold the rolled number and check if it is 1, then break out of the loop if it is

```
def rollingdice(roll): #define function
    total = 0 #starting count
    for i in range(roll):
        rolled = random.randint(1, 6)
        if rolled == 1:
            print("You rolled a 1: You have zero points for the round")
            break
        total += rolled

    if rolled != 1: print(total)
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import random

def rollingdice(roll):
    rolls = (random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(roll))
    rolls = list(takewhile(lambda n: n != 1, rolls))
    if len(rolls) == roll:
        print(total)
    else:
        print("You rolled a 1: You have zero points for the round")
```